# How to handle errors of CLLocationManager?

Tags: iphone, core-location

Well, I know technically how to intercept an error, but what *should I do* in any case CLLocationManager or Core Location doesn't work? What are your strategies, what do you show to the user?

Comment: Might want to flesh the question out with some use examples. As the question stands now the answer is try, try again and then give up. Then tell the user you can get the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a few things.

1) Use a default location that might make sense.
2) Ask the user to center a map on their location and use that.